# Annoying message pops up when voting

Tags: discussion

I upvote answer regularly, because I think answers deserve encouragement. But after every couple of votes I get a popup that I haven't voted for questions in a while. I find this very annoying, especially since voting for a question doen't seem to help; a few days later it's there again.
I feel compelled to vote for questions I don't want to vote for. What are the criteria for getting this kind of message?

Comment: You should be happy it's just a pop-up and not a forceful lockout like everything else on these sites...

Comment: @endolith - I believe that all of the lockouts are useful.  If there are any which you feel are unjust, please feel free to open a meta question.

Comment: @Kevin: They've all been brought up on meta before, and users have [registered their disagreement](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19940/undo-a-up-down-vote-after-a-comment-is-left/21839#21839) accordingly.  Not that it will do any good.

Comment: Only 6% of your votes are for questions (Q:42/A:690). For me the ratio is Q:615/A:306, and I've never had that popup. Just vote a bit more on questions, before you look at the answers.

Comment: Think that a good answer may be generated by a good question

Answer (score 4):

Questions deserve encouragement, too!  It's very hard to write good questions.  For me, it's harder than writing answers!  Quality questions deserve upvotes.

However, many users (like you) primarily upvote answers.  The problem was discussed in the blog post ["Vote For This Question or The Kitten Gets It"](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/05/vote-for-this-question-or-the-kitten-gets-it/) (Here's a picture of the kitten):
[image]
*every time you forget to vote a great question up, or a bad question down — a kitten gets it!*

Joking aside, one way that they decided to [approach the problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9508/why-arent-people-voting-for-questions) was the popup that you mentioned.  This popup appears if you haven’t voted on at least one question in the last 15 votes you cast.  After this happens, the popup appears every time you vote until you do.  (If you can't find any good questions to vote on, then we've got different problem.  I understand that you may feel like it's compelling you to vote on the question you're currently viewing, but that's not the intent.)

Another way was adjusting the voting metrics.  Previously, everyone got 30 votes per day to use as they saw fit.  Now, everyone gets 40 votes per day, but at least 10 must be on questions.

Finally, there are a couple of badges to encourage voting on questions.  The [Electorate](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/badges/28/electorate) gold badge is given when you have oted on 600 questions and 25% or more of total votes are on questions. That 25% ratio is probably a good number.  The [Vox Populi](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/badges/69/vox-populi) bronze badge is given when you use all 40 votes in one day - Since, as I mentioned earlier, you can only vote on 30 answers, this also encourages voting on questions.

From [your profile](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/3920/federico-russo), I see that you've voted for 366 answers and 27 questions.  Try to bump that ratio a bit!  The popup is there on purpose.

Comment: But if someone doesn't feel comfortable voting on questions or just doesn't want to for whatever reason, it doesn't seem to me it's anyone else's business nor that the site should nag him about it.

Comment: @Olin -  It's to everyone's advantage for the site to encourage behaviors that make the site more useful, and [voting is important](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/vote-early-vote-often/)!  It's also important for the site to discourage or prevent harmful behaviors.

Comment: And not a single comment worrying about Kittens. You heartless %*&^$.

Comment: @Olin: You are free to ignore the nag messages.  You can probably block the messages with Adblock Plus Element Hiding Helper if it really bothers you that much.

Comment: @endolith: the fact that I posted here about it is a sign that they're not so easy to ignore :-(

Comment: @Kortuk: Save the mice!